# ElementAt method in Dictionary before .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, DataRow>` that uses the ElementAt() method.  It works great in .NET 3.5 and above.  However, my ISP seems to be running some pre-.NET 3.5 version that doesn't understand the method, rendering the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary< int,System.Data.DataRow >' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'

The reason I need to use ElementAt is because I want to pick random dictionary elements and then remove that element until all elements have been displayed randomly

```
                int key = testimonialDictionary.ElementAt(rnd).Key;
... do something with the Value / DataRow
                testimonialDictionary.Remove(key);
```

My question is, what did people use before ElementAt()?  How do I implement this?

Comment: dictionaries really don't have any ordering so that is potentially flawed.

Comment: It is a Linq extension method.  Use the Keys property instead.

Comment: `Dictionary<>` does not allow random access to its keys, which means selecting a random one will be an expensive O(n) operation. Keep this in mind :).

Comment: Do you mean that `ElementAt` works on your local computer running .NET < 3.5, but doesn't work on the ISP computer running the same version? Or do you mean that you tested your code on a different OS than you're running it on?

Comment: Can you use something *besides* a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would be simple way to implement it

```
string ElementAt(Dictionary<string,string> dict, uint index)
{   
    if(dict.Count > index)
    {
        uint iCnt =0;
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> val in dict)
        {
            if(index == iCnt)
                return val.Key;
            iCnt++;
            if(index < iCnt)
               return null;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Test it

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"A","1"},{"B","2"},{"C","3"},{"D","4"},{"E","5"}};

for(uint i=0;i<5;i++)
    Console.WriteLine(ElementAt(dict,i));
```

Comment: A dictionary does not ensure to keep the ordering, this is a implementation detail i would not rely on

Comment: Ohh, if that is the case one should never use ElementAt on dictionary, I simply put the way that can be done. One can use SortedDictionary though for such purpose if required :)

Comment: A more general version: `static TElement ElementAt<TElement>(this ICollection<TElement> collection, int index)
    {
      if (collection == null)
      { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }
      if (index < 0 || index >= collection.Count)
      { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }

      int count = 0;
      foreach (var e in collection)
      {
        if (count == index)
        { return e; }

        ++count;
      }

      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The enumeration yielded only {0} elements, but Count property was {1}.", count, collection.Count);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you want to get *all* the dictionary elements in a random order

> I want to pick random dictionary elements and then remove that element until all elements have been displayed randomly

... the answers that get you keys one at a time end up being O(n^2), because it's O(n) to get one key out and you have to do it O(n) times.

This is how I'd do it instead:

1. Get all the dictionary keys out into an array. This is still possible before LINQ, but I did have to look it up!

```
var keys = new int[testimonialDictionary.Count];
testimonialDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
```

2. Perform a Fisher-Yates shuffle on the key array to put the keys into a random order.

```
var r = new Random();
for (int i = keys.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    var putIntoI = r.Next(i + 1);
    var temp = keys[putIntoI];
    keys[putIntoI] = keys[i];
    keys[i] = temp;
}
```

3. Iterate through the keys in this random order, displaying them as required and (if you really need to) removing them from the dictionary too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    // Display the key and/or its corresponding value
    Display(keys[i], testimonialDictionary[keys[i]]);

    // Remove the item from the dictionary if you have to
    testimonialDictionary.Remove(keys[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about we go more python style:

```
int key = testimonialDictionary.Keys.ToArray()[rnd];

testimonialDictionary.Remove(key);
```

Make sure your rnd is not greater than the number of keys you have minus one or less than 0!!

UPDATE: As somone pointed out, .ToArray() is also linq, so use this instead:

```
int i = 0;
int? key = null
foreach(int k in testimonialDictionary.Keys){
    if(i==rnd){
        key = k;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
testimonialDictionary.Remove(key)
```

(Shame you can't use .Skip() in 3.5)

Comment: `.ToArray` is part of linq too.

Comment: Could be kind of expensive - convert all the keys to an array just so you can index?